# Padding has unexpected effect on drop down menu with absolute postioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, padding

I have `#header` div with the following css properties:

```
#header{
    background-image:url('img/header-bkg-tile.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

and `#header-container` inside it with this properties:

```
#header-container{
    height:63px;
    width: 1120px;
    position: relative;
    left : 50%;
    margin-left: -560px;
    padding-top:19px;
}
```

The structure is this just in case:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `#header` you have an image and a `<ul>`, and everything is working as expected.

My problem is when creating this `simple dropdow`.

The issue itself is that I cant reach the lower parts of the `.sub_menu`, the dropdown goes back to the "resting position" after you go under the penultimate element.

You can see a [live example here](http://trufavarela.com/uruware/).

I have isolated the problem and it has to do with the padding I am using to centre the image vertically: `padding-top:19px;`

The relevant code of the dropdown is the following:

```
/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li                      { float: left; zoom: 1; }
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #000; }
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px;}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: black; }

/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { width: 220px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;}
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #C8E4ED; color: #000; 
                                      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none; }

                                    /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
```

I have tried a wide variety of things but to be honest I was more or less guessing, and I would like to understand what's the problem.

I would have though adding a negative padding to the `LEVEL TWO` elements would have solve the issue but it doesn't so any pointers could help.

EDIT: The header markup is the following:

```
 <div id="header">
     <div id="header-container">
         <div id="header-all">
             <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo uruware"/></a>
             <ul id="header-elements" class="dropdown">
                 <li><a href="#" class="active-selection">Inicio</a>
                  <ul class="sub_menu">
                        <li><a href="#1">UCFE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2">Trx Server</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3">Trx Framework</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Quiénes somos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Productos</a>

                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If its not too much trouble convert your example to a jsfiddle, alternatively post your header markup.

Comment: @Nix added the header mark-up and I'm working on a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Nix now I'm really lost because I can't reproduce the error! http://jsfiddle.net/E4gRB/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @Nix thanks for the help it was a z-index problem! see bbxdesigns answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `z-index`issue.

The rule is that everything that comes *after* in your HTML code is *above*. As a result, your div `#container`, which comes *after* your ul dropdown is **above** your ul dropdown.

To fix that, add this to your dropdown:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

Or just `z-index: 1;`, as long as you **set** your z-index.

Comment: I swear I could not up vote you enough! You've made may day! Thanks a ton!